# Can A String array be passed as a parameter to a method that takes object array as argument?

Tags: java, object-oriented

*Why after declaring a variable for String array, it can be passed to a method that accepts object array? Now, `String` is a class by itself so I assumed a long time ago that all variable is object at a sense. But many argued with me about it. But here it shows the same kind of behaviour.*

**Below is given the code where the passing works and the comments point them out.**

```
public class Knuth {
private Knuth() { }

// HERE SHOWS IT TAKES OBJECT
public static void shuffle(Object[] a)

{
int n = a.length;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
int r = (int) (Math.random() * (i + 1));
Object swap = a[r];
a[r] = a[i];
a[i] = swap;
}
}

public static void shuffleAlternate(Object[] a) {
int n = a.length;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
int r = i + (int) (Math.random() * (n - i));
Object swap = a[r];
a[r] = a[i];
a[i] = swap;
}
}


public static void main(String[] args) {

// HERE SHOWS IT IS PASSING STRING ARRAY
String[] a = StdIn.readAllStrings();
 
        Knuth.shuffle(a);

for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
StdOut.println(a[i]);
}
}
```

Comment: Did you write this? Do you always indent your code like this? What is the goal of the code? Please take a look at the [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 1):

String extends Object type: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html
This means that String's superclass is Object, so any function that requires an Object as parameter will accept String as parameter also. You can read here about inheritance for example: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_inheritance.htm